# Load JavaScript into a page I do not own before any of its JavaScript executes

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, testing

I have found a web page I don't have control over. I can see in its console that it is throwing a "missing jQuery" error from its Bootstrap script.

I'd like to load jQuery before this script executes when I navigate to this page so I can see if the site operates differently.

Comment: If you just want to test it out, you can probably just copy/paste the markup from the page in question into something like jsFiddle, fix the jQuery URL, and possibly other URL's that aren't absolute as well, and view the webpage there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR**
Yes, it's possible, but not the conventional way

## Why no

You can't run Javascript on arbitrary Web pages that you do not control the content of. It would be a huge security hole if that were not true.

Think about it: you could run Javascript and wait for someone to log on to their internet banking and then do something with the characters input.

## Why yes

However, if you just want to get the page working, you can use [Tampermonkey](https://tampermonkey.net/). You can use it to execute custom scripts on page load for any website you want. You can find some basic tutorials here: https://hibbard.eu/tampermonkey-tutorial/

Comment: as the question is clearly tagged `google-chrome`, use [TamperMonkey](http://tampermonkey.net/) instead (available on Chrome/Firefox/Edge/Safari/Opera Next/ etc) - actually, I think in Chrome you don't even need TamperMonkey, as user scripts can be (at least could be in the past) "added natively"

Comment: Good point, overlooked that. I'll edit the answer to reflect that.

Comment: actually, TamperMonkey is a better solution than Chrome's native user script handling, as with TampeMonkey you can inject the code "very early" in the page loading sequence, whereas I'm not sure with the "native" method you could inject the code early enough